# c# in memory query of objects without linq

Tags: c#, collections

We are still using .Net Framework 2.0 / VS 2005 so i do not have LINQ. If i don't want to go with the [poor man's LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq2005.aspx) solution, what are some other alternatives for being able to query in memory custom objects in a dictionary?

Comment: I would have thought that the answer to this would be "the same way people always did this, before LINQ came around". Is there any particular data retrieval code, that you are finding difficult to write? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if one of your poor man's LINQ solution is [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) but I used it for a few weeks and it seemed to be working *okay* before we actually switched to .NET 3.5 and the real deal.

Comment: @zespri ah, maybe he should try LINQBridge and see how it weights against what he has tried so far.

Comment: @zespri that post says you can use it in vs2005. `You can—but the query operators will be awkward to use without lambda expressions, extension methods, query syntax, etc.`

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry about this than.

Comment: @BalaR What if there is no LINQ??how can do it before linq?

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<T>` would seem like a good choice, although you haven't provided much information about what you mean by "query." Are you just looking to retrieve data based on some key value? Get a count of total items? Do a sum or average based on some condition? You really need to give more information to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what Chesso said, you'll have to iterate the loop just like LINQ does...

for example:

```
    static T FindFirst<T>(IEnumerable<T> col, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        foreach(T t in col)
        {
            if(predicate(t))
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of the Predicate delegate, that seems to be pretty much what i was looking for. As far as the context for which i'm querying:

Say i have a object X with properties A (name, guaranteed to be unique) and B (age)

1) I have a series of objects in a dictionary whose keys are say Property A of a given object, and of course the value is the object iself.

Now i want to retrieve all objects in this dictionary which meet a certain criteria of B, say age > 20.

I can add all the values of the dictionary into a list then call the .FindAll on it, passing in a delegate. I can create an anonymous delegate to do this, but say i will reuse this many times. How can i dynamically specify an age criteria for the delegate method? Would the only choice be to encapsulate the Predicate method in a class, then create a new instance of that class with my criteria as an instance variable?